# TFS 2010 Sharepoint Web Part error

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I downloaded: 
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010 and Team Foundation Server® 2010 Beta 2 for Microsoft® Virtual PC 2007 SP1 Image
When I go into the default installation of TFS project site in Sharepoint ( http://vs2010beta2/sites/DefaultCollection/IBuySpy/Dashboards/ProjectDashboard_wss.aspx   ) I get this error on the webparts. ***There are no accessible team projects in this Team Project Collection. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.***
In the Team Server Admin Console - Team Project Collection - Team Projects tab the projects are there.  This is the default installation.  Any suggestions???

Answer (score 2):

1. Open **Team Explorer**
2. Right click your [TeamProject]
3. Select **Team Project Settings** > **Group Membership**
4. Select **[TeamProject]\Readers** group and click **properties**
5. Add your user or team groups

Comment: This makes so much sense when you write it out this simply, but for the life of me, I couldn't figure it out without searching. Thanks!